# Unable to set date time field CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a mutator:

```
protected function _setPurchaseTime($purchase_time) {
    return Time($purchase_time);
}
```

This mutator gets run fine when I set the value like this:

```
$transaction->purchase_time = $this->request->data['purchase_time'];
```

The mutator correctly gets `$purchase_time`. But when I try to set it like this:

```
$transaction = $this->Transactions->patchEntity($transaction, $this->request->data);
```

`$purchase_time` is null. I can't figure out why this would be the case? The mutator gets run just fine, but the variable is null.

EDIT:

I should also add that `purchase_time` is accessible:

```
protected $_accessible = [
 'ticker' => TRUE,
 'name' => TRUE,
 'market' => TRUE,
 'transaction_type' => TRUE,
 'price' => TRUE,
 'currency' => TRUE,
 'commission' => TRUE,
 'shares' => TRUE,
 'purchase_time' => TRUE
];
```

Edit: Added extra data

This is the data going into patchEntity:

```
[
  'ticker_label' => 'AAPL (Apple Inc.)',
  'ticker' => 'AAPL',
  'currency' => 'USD',
  'market' => 'NASDAQ',
  'transaction_type' => 'Buy',
  'price' => '10',
  'commission' => '10',
  'shares' => '10',
  'date' => 'Yesterday',
  'purchase_time' => 'July 12, 2015 12:00',
  'time' => '12:00',
  'name' => 'Apple Inc.'
]
```

And this is the data after patchEntity is run:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {
  'portfolio_id' => '43',
  'ticker' => 'AAPL',
  'currency' => 'USD',
  'market' => 'NASDAQ',
  'transaction_type' => 'Buy',
  'price' => (float) 10,
  'commission' => (float) 10,
  'shares' => (float) 10,
  'purchase_time' => (int) 1436803512,
  'name' => 'Apple Inc.',
  '[new]' => true,
  '[accessible]' => [
    'ticker' => true,
    'name' => true,
    'market' => true,
    'transaction_type' => true,
    'price' => true,
    'currency' => true,
    'commission' => true,
    'shares' => true,
    'purchase_time' => true
  ],
  '[dirty]' => [
    'portfolio_id' => true,
    'ticker' => true,
    'currency' => true,
    'market' => true,
    'transaction_type' => true,
    'price' => true,
    'commission' => true,
    'shares' => true,
    'purchase_time' => true,
    'name' => true
  ],
  '[original]' => [],
  '[virtual]' => [],
  '[errors]' => [],
  '[repository]' => 'Transactions'
}
```

As you can see, if you do the conversion of the Unix timestamp in the `purchase_time` field, it does not equal the input. It equals the current time now, which is expected when passing in a `NULL` value into `Time()`.

Comment: You probably have validation errors

Comment: @JoséLorenzo I have zero validation at the moment, haven't set any up yet as I wanted to get this working first before I added validation.

Comment: What is the result of debug($transaction) after the patch entity?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo added extra data going into patchEntity and what comes out of patchEntity.

Comment: So, you have a localized date going into the the data array. Did you enable the `useLocaleParser()` ?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo That shouldn't be necessary, the date isn't localized, nor does it need to be. The user inputs a date, that date is stored, and shown exactly as it's stored. Nothing changes based on time zone or anything.

Comment: Dates are not usually stored in a localized format. Is the column a date filed or a string field?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo The column is a DateTime field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `DatetimeType` class in CakePHP expects the input in a normalized format. Either as an array (the form inputs) or as a string in ISO format.

Since you are providing an input in a localized format, you either need to [enable the locale parser](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#parsing-localized-datetime-data), send the input in the ISO format, transform the data before it is converted to datetime, or extend the `DateTimeType` class to fit your needs.

One simple way of doing this is using the `Model.beforeMarshal` event:

```
$table->eventManager()->on('Model.beforeMarshal', function ($event, $data) {
    if (!empty($data['the_time_field']) {
        $data['the_time_field'] = new Time($data['the_time_field'])
    }
});
```

It is important to remember that data is not set to the entity if it cannot be correctly validated or if it cannot be "parsed" byt the Marshaller with the help of the Type classes. This is the reason your setter was not being called when using patchEntity.

Comment: Thanks José, this solves the initial problem of the setter not working, and actually makes the setter completely redundant. But it doesn't solve the issue of not being able to save the data. I've checked the variable after `patchEntity` is called and it's a time object, as expected. However, when saved to the database, everything else saves fine, but the datetime column is set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: you are probably setting the name of a column that is different to the name of the column in the database

Comment: I have verified that the name of value within the entity object is `purchase_time`, and the name of the column in the database is `purchase_time`, I'm not sure where else I could be misnaming something?

Comment: No idea! I'm out of clues. I you have some reproducible error in a simple app try to open an issue in github